# Run a music in background with Playsound c++

Tags: c++, background, playsound

I would like to create a game on the c++ console with a music in background, with the Playsound funtion. As there everything work, the music run but block the rest of the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
//*********************
#define GRID 10
#define VSL5 5
#define VSL4 4
#define VSL3 3
#define VSL2 2
#define VSL1 1
#define CORNER
//*********************

using namespace std;
bool music;

char grille[GRID][GRID];                                                                                    //On crée la grille de jeu

bool Played = PlaySound("Music_fond.wav", NULL, SND_SYNC);
int main() {
//************************ Creation and cout of the grid

cout << Played;

for (int y = 0; y < GRID; y++) {                                                                        //Avec cette boucle for j'initialise toutes les cases du jeu avec un point en commencant par les y
    for (int x = 0; x < GRID; x++) {                                                                    //Avec cette boucle for j'initialise toutes les cases x du jeu avec un point
        grille[x][y] = '.';
        
    }
}

for (int y = 0; y < GRID; y++) {                                                                        //Avec cette boucle for j'affiche toutes les cases du jeu
    for (int x = 0; x < GRID; x++) {                                                                    //Avec cette boucle for j'affiche toutes les cases x du jeu
        cout << grille[x][y] << " ";
        Beep(12000, 15);
        Sleep(5);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
//********************** end Creation of the grid
```

In this code I initialize all the grid case to the '.' character. I'm making the grid of my game.
With the first for loop, I initialise the cases
In the seconde I print them.
But the code stay stuck in the Playsound function, I guess that it wait for th emusic to finish, but I would like the music to be runned in background and let the code go
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you should replace `SND_SYNC` with `SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP`

Answer (score 2):

The `SND_SYNC` flag means the function will block until the sound ends.

You should use `SND_ASYNC` instead.

For more information, see [PlaySound function (Windows) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85))